# How can use pdfmake in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, typescript2.0, pdfmake

I'm trying to create pdf in ionic2 with pdfmake.

I added the library to my app:

```
$ npm install pdfmake --save
```

Import it into class

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, ToastController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as pdfmake from 'pdfmake'
```

But, When I try to instantiate and use the method, the displayed error in the device:

```
var dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
    ],
    pageSize: 'A4',
    pageMargins: [25, 25, 25, 25],
};

// download the PDF
var pdf = new pdfmake();
pdf.createPdf( dd ).download();
```

Runtime Error:

```
fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

How can I use pdfmake in ionic 2? Is it possible

[image]

Comment: Did you try import pdfmake from 'pdfmake'? CommonJS modules and all

Comment: Yes, I try without * , but don't work form me.

Comment: @misha130 about "CommonJS modules and all", sorry, I didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... again... After many days, I finally get the pdfmake to work on my project with pdfmake community's help .

I cloned the compiled version into the www folder

```
$ cd  project/www/
$ git clone https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake.git
```

Then I added the scripts to the index.

```
<body>

  <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
  <ion-app></ion-app>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

  <!-- The bundle js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
  <script src='pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js'></script>
  <script src='pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and replace import to ...

```
import * as pdfmake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
```

[Pdfmake community response](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/864#issuecomment-280908652)

[Github with project test](https://github.com/calraiden/cal-pdfmake-test)

Comment: When I am adding project like this in Ionic 2  
 "clone https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake.git"

it gives me error 
'clone' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file